# How do I append something to the innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine

```
function move(where){
            var status = document.querySelector("#status");
            var img = document.querySelector("img");

            switch(where){
                case "north":
                    if(startingPos>=3){
                        startingPos -= 3;
                        status.innerHTML = messages[startingPos];
                        img.setAttribute("src",images[startingPos]);
                    }else{
                        status.innerHTML = blockedPathMsg[startingPos];
                    }
                    break;
                case "east":
                    if(startingPos%3!=2){
                        startingPos += 1;
                        status.innerHTML = messages[startingPos];
                        img.setAttribute("src",images[startingPos]);
                    }else{
                        status.innerHTML = blockedPathMsg[startingPos];
                    }
                    break;
                case "west":
                    if(startingPos%3!=0){
                        startingPos -= 1;
                        status.innerHTML = messages[startingPos];
                        img.setAttribute("src",images[startingPos]);
                    }else{
                        status.innerHTML = blockedPathMsg[startingPos];
                    }
                    break;
                case "south":
                    if(startingPos<6){
                        startingPos += 3;
                        status.innerHTML = messages[startingPos];
                        img.setAttribute("src",images[startingPos]);
                    }else{
                        status.innerHTML = blockedPathMsg[startingPos];
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    status.innerHTML = "I do not know that";
            }
        }
```

This is the function that I use in my game where the user can move around. Now I need to add a new feature where the user can pick and drop items. Items will be at certain spots in the map and whenever the user reaches there I want to append the message associated with that item to `status.innerHTML`.

How do I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append you can use:

```
status.innerHTML += ' what to add';
```

This is the same syntactically as using:

```
status.innerHTML = status.innerHTML + ' what to add';
```

Comment: Please don't. This is such a bad technique.

Comment: @amnotiam while this isn't the best solution, and DOM modification should be used, it answers the question that has been asked. DOM modification would require a large rewrite/change of the code that is currently there.

Comment: A rewrite is better than teaching bad practices. While pretty harmless if this is only short text, it can be terrible in other situations.

Answer (score -1):

If you use JQuery, there is a very easy way to do this using the append() function. See this link for some examples: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: The code the user has posted is not using jQuery, therefore assume that they aren't using it.

Comment: Although this would be a very helpful comment on the original question